# Incrementing a value inside a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key, vectorization

I  am trying to model a bag of words. I am having some trouble incrementing the counter inside my dictionary when the word is found in my data (type series):

```
def build_voc(self, data):
        for document in data:
            for word in document.split(' '):
                if word in self.voc:
                    self.voc_ctr[word] = self.voc_ctr[word] + 1
                else:
                    self.voc.append(word)
                    self.voc_ctr = 1
```

I tried indexing it as well this way just to test where the error was:

```
self.voc_ctr[word][0] = self.voc_ctr[word][0] + 1
```

But it still gives me the same error at that line:

> TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Knowing that this is a function in the same class, where self.voc and self.voc_ctr are defined:

```
class BV:
    def __init__(self):
        self.voc = []
        self.voc_ctr = {}

    def build_voc(self, data):
        for document in data:
            for word in document.split(' '):
                if word in self.voc:
                    self.voc_ctr[word] = self.voc_ctr[word] + 1
                else:
                    self.voc.append(word)
                    self.voc_ctr = 1
```

The error seems to say self.voc_ctr is an int object, but I defined it as a list so I don't know where I went wrong.

Comment: I think that in the else statement you set `voc_ctr` as int but not dict. Maybe you want to set `voc_ctr[word]=1`. Im not in front of a computer, but with a brief that what i was found

Comment: It worked thanks :) But how come the error kept happening at that line under the "if" and not under the "else" ?

Comment: Thats because at first it go through your else and initiate the vairable, after when you try act like the variable is dict, the compiler dont understand you because it already an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't going into your "if" statement first, it's going into your "else" and initializing your self.voc_ctr to the integer, 1.

It look like you have more going on than just a counter not working. In this part of code:

```
if word in self.voc:
    self.voc_ctr[word] = self.voc_ctr[word] + 1
```

...you're saying "If the word is in my list, create a dictionary entry containing that word and assign the value of the entry AFTER that new entry to it." Once you correct your initial 'int' error, you're going to get a KeyError. Since self.voc_ctr[word] won't exists until AFTER the assignment operation is complete, self.voc_ctr[word] + 1 won't exist either.

To implement a counter for each word, try doing this:

```
if word in self.voc:
    self.voc_ctr[word] = 1
else:
    self.voc_ctr[word] = 0
```

I don't know what else you have to do with this program, but this will solve your counter issue.

Comment: Then shouldn't the compiler indicate the error at that line ?

Comment: No. It's legal syntax. The interpreter only knows what you say, not what you mean, and changing things like that isn't an error. I'm editing my answer now to give you more information.

Comment: After your edit: Isn't the dictionary entry going to be created when I use it before the assignment?

Comment: The dictionary will, but the element [word] within the dictionary won't be. Look at the dictionary as a book shelf. When you declare it, you're putting the bookshelf up...but you still have to put the books in it. In your code, you're not putting any books in before you try to take them out.

Comment: I got that, but what I mean is : isn't the book "word" going to be created when I use it the first time? Like the order of operations here seems like:
1.Create a dictionary,   2.Create new entry "word",   3.Add 1 to entry,   4.Assign entry "word" to new entry "word"

Comment: In your code, you're not creating the entry until your "if" statement. Keep in mind that operations work from the right to the left, so you're saying "Take the entry after voc_ctr[word] and assign it to voc_ctr[word]". Since you don't create voc_ctr[word] before that, you'll get a KeyError.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223207/discussion-between-firdaws-and-tyler).

Answer (score 1):

```
   def build_voc(self, data):
    for document in data:
        for word in document.split(' '):
            if word in self.voc:
                self.voc_ctr[word] = self.voc_ctr[word] + 1
            else:
                self.voc.append(word)
                self.voc_ctr = 1       ## <-------- The function fails here
```

The way you are doing is not the best/optimal way to do it, you do not need a list to first check and then add it to a dictionary

Dictionary itself is the best way to check if the word exists or not

Try to use the modified version

```
   voc_ctr = {}
   def build_voc(data):
    for document in data:
        for word in document.split(' '):
            if word in voc:
                voc_ctr[word] += 1
            else:
                voc_ctr = 1
```